# Mpmath : quadprog or lsei equivalent?

Tags: python, constraints, quadratic-programming, mpmath, quadprog

I want to solve a quadratic program with mpmath precision. The problem can be stated as a least square with linear equality and inequality constraints, or as quadratic program with linear equality and inequality constraints.

I am aware of the `LSEI` fortran routine, which is accessible from `R`, `python`, and other software. the `solve.QP` from `R` `quadprog` package is also perfect for this task. Finaly, the `SLSQP` fortran routine does also the job properly.

However i need arbitrary precision and for that i'm using the `mpmath` pyhton library. Are you aware of some implementaiton of one of these algorithmes for `mpmath` ?

Comment: I know of quad precision solvers but I am not aware of arbitrary precision solvers. I guess they would be prohibitively slow. There are rational MIP solvers. Maybe that can be used to solve the KKT conditions.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Yeah i did not found anything either. I agree, they will probably be very very slow, but so usefull :)